# weird access violation error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, direct3d10

I'm getting a (to me) weird run-time access violation error.
I have a class, GUI, that contains a raw pointer to an instance of another class, Crosshair. However, when I try to access that pointer, I get a run-time error! I'm talking about accessing the pointer, I don't even have to dereference it to get the error.

Here's the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00d4c486 in GPEngine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

The error returns to this line: `int a = (int)m_pCrosshair;`
Which is in the `GUI::Draw()` method, provided below.

---

### EDIT:

I found the problem. It occurred in code I was hiding from you guys, while trying to hide as much irrelevant code as possible... The problem was this:

```
bool PsychoBots_Game::InitGame()
{
//more code...
return true;
//////GUI
    GUIOnIntialisationInfo GUIdesc;
    GUIdesc.pContentManager = m_pContentManager;
    GUIdesc.pDevice = m_pLevel->GetDevice();

    m_pGUI = new GUI(GUIdesc);
}
```

Pure stupidity, in other words... Sorry for this! I did not write the first part of that method so I wasn't aware of the return values since I never use this when initialising my own stuff...

---

### Old:

Code:

**Crosshair.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "D3DUtil.h"

class ContentManager;
class RenderContext;

class Crosshair
{
public:
    Crosshair(ID3D10Device* pDevice, ContentManager *pContentManager);
    virtual ~Crosshair();

    void Draw(ID3D10Device* pDevice, int clientWidth, int clientHeight);

private:
    ID3D10InputLayout*          m_pVertexLayout;
    ID3D10Buffer*               m_pVertexBuffer;

    ID3D10Effect*               m_pDefaultEffect;
    ID3D10EffectTechnique*      m_pDefaultTechnique;

    ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable* m_pWVPVariable;
    ID3D10EffectShaderResourceVariable* m_pDiffuseMapVariabele;

    ID3D10ShaderResourceView *  m_pTextureRV;

private:
    //disabled
    Crosshair(const Crosshair& b);
    Crosshair& operator= (const Crosshair& b);
};
```

---

**Crosshair.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Crosshair.h"

#include "ContentManager.h"
#include "RenderContext.h"

#include "vertex.h"

Crosshair::Crosshair(ID3D10Device* pDevice, ContentManager *pContentManager)
    :m_pVertexLayout(nullptr)
    ,m_pVertexBuffer(nullptr)
    ,m_pDefaultEffect(nullptr)
    ,m_pDefaultTechnique(nullptr)
    ,m_pWVPVariable(nullptr)
    ,m_pDiffuseMapVariabele(nullptr)
    ,m_pTextureRV(nullptr)
{
//////Load Texture
    m_pTextureRV = pContentManager->GetTexture(pDevice, _T("GUI/Crosshair.png"));

//////Load Effect & Technique
    m_pDefaultEffect = pContentManager->GetEffect(pDevice,  _T("Effect/Texture2D.fx"));

    //get  technique 
    m_pDefaultTechnique = m_pDefaultEffect->GetTechniqueByIndex(0);
    if(!m_pDefaultTechnique->IsValid())
    {
        MessageBox(0,_T("Technique not valid"),_T("ERROR"),0);
        exit(-1);
    }

//////Get Effect Variables
    m_pDiffuseMapVariabele = m_pDefaultEffect->GetVariableBySemantic("DiffuseMap")->AsShaderResource();
    if(!m_pDiffuseMapVariabele->IsValid()) {
        MessageBox(0,_T("Getting EffectVariable m_pDiffuseMapVariabele Failed"),_T("ERROR"),0);
        exit(-1);
    }

    m_pWVPVariable = m_pDefaultEffect->GetVariableBySemantic("WVP")->AsMatrix();
    if(!m_pWVPVariable->IsValid()) {
        MessageBox(0,_T("Getting EffectVariable m_pWVPVariable Failed"),_T("ERROR"),0);
        exit(-1);
    }

//////Define InputLayout
    D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };
    UINT numElements = sizeof(layout)/sizeof(layout[0]);

    // Create the input layout
    D3D10_PASS_DESC PassDesc;
    // Get the pass decriptor from the effect technique
    m_pDefaultTechnique->GetPassByIndex( 0 )->GetDesc( &PassDesc );
    HR(pDevice->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, PassDesc.pIAInputSignature, PassDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &m_pVertexLayout ));

//////Build Vertexbuffer
    VertexPosTex v[4];

    v[0].pos = D3DXVECTOR3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f); v[0].tex.x = 0.0f; v[0].tex.y = 1.0f;
    v[1].pos = D3DXVECTOR3(-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f); v[1].tex.x = 0.0f; v[1].tex.y = 0.0f;
    v[2].pos = D3DXVECTOR3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f); v[2].tex.x = 1.0f; v[2].tex.y = 1.0f;
    v[3].pos = D3DXVECTOR3( 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f); v[3].tex.x = 1.0f; v[3].tex.y = 0.0f;

    //fill a buffer description to copy the vertexdata into graphics memory
    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC bd = {};
    bd.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( VertexPosTex ) * sizeof(v);
    bd.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bd.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    initData.pSysMem = v;
    //create a ID3D10Buffer in graphics memory containing the vertex info
    HR(pDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &initData, &m_pVertexBuffer ));
}

Crosshair::~Crosshair()
{
    m_pVertexLayout->Release();
    m_pVertexBuffer->Release();
}

void Crosshair::Draw(ID3D10Device* pDevice, int clientWidth, int clientHeight)
{
//////Set the input layout
    pDevice->IASetInputLayout( m_pVertexLayout );

//more code...
}
```

---

**GUI.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "D3DUtil.h"

#include "GUIOnInitialisationInfo.h"
#include "GUIPerFrameInfo.h"
#include "GUIPerTickInfo.h"

#include "Crosshair.h"

class GUI
{
public:
    virtual ~GUI();
    GUI(const GUIOnIntialisationInfo& info);

    void Tick(const GUIPerTickInfo& info);
    void Draw(const GUIPerFrameInfo& info);

private:
    Crosshair* m_pCrosshair;
};
```

---

**GUI.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GUI.h"
GUI::GUI(const GUIOnIntialisationInfo& info)
    :m_pCrosshair(new Crosshair(info.pDevice, info.pContentManager))
{
}
GUI::~GUI()
{
    delete m_pCrosshair;
}
void GUI::Tick(const GUIPerTickInfo& info)
{
}
void GUI::Draw(const GUIPerFrameInfo& info)
{
    int a = (int)m_pCrosshair; 
    m_pCrosshair->Draw(info.pDevice, info.clientWidth, info.clientHeight);
}
```

The error returns to this line: `int a = (int)m_pCrosshair;`

*When I delete this line: it will break at* `m_pCrosshair->Draw(info.pDevice, info.clientWidth,info.clientHeight);`

*With error:* `Unhandled exception at 0x001fc49a in GPEngine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004`

---

**Here is how an instance of GUI is intantiated in my application:**

```
class PsychoBots_Game : public D3DApp
{
//more code...
private:
    GUI* m_pGUI;
//more code...
};
```

*(please don't ask me why I have an InitGame() method, we have to do this to make our teachers happy [lol])*

```
bool PsychoBots_Game::InitGame()
{
//////GUI
    GUIOnIntialisationInfo GUIdesc;
    GUIdesc.pContentManager = m_pContentManager;
    GUIdesc.pDevice = m_pLevel->GetDevice();

    m_pGUI = new GUI(GUIdesc);
}
```

And finally, WinMain:

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
                   TCHAR* cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    PsychoBots_Game *pGameApp= new PsychoBots_Game(hInstance);

    if(pGameApp->InitApp())pGameApp->Run();
    delete pGameApp;
}
```

---

Can anyone tell me what is causing the problem? If by any chance you still need more code, just ask in a comment :)

Thanks

Comment: Actually it would be much easier to help you if there was _less_ code. Can you provide a [minimal](http://sscce.org/), failing example? Or *at least* tell us the line where the access violation occurs. It should be pretty straightforward to debug this code using a proper IDE.

Comment: I tried to provide as few code as possible. I'll highlight the area where the error occurs though.

Comment: Do you use an IDE? Most of them have the option to debug your code step-by-step or at least can tell you the line where the access violation occured.

Comment: Yes, visual studio. I gave up the line where the it breaks in the top of the question to try make it more clear

Comment: Can you add a `printf("m_pContentManager = %p\n", m_pContentManager);` before the failing line to check whether it's a valid pointer (the error indicates that it is NULL)

Comment: Is m_pCrosshair initialized? What I mean is, that the CrossHair object should be created with the InitGame(), but does it really create the object, or does the constructor return false value?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark do you mean m_pCrosshair? Because there's nothing wrong with the pointer to the contentmanager?

Comment: @xcrypt: yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: @koressak InitGame() returns true, just checked.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark I tried `printf("m_pCrosshair = %p\n", m_pCrosshair);` as first line in GUI::Draw(), but when I try to run the code it gives a break error! (remember, m_pCrosshair can't even be accessed for *some* reason), at least not in the Draw() method, I'll try it in the constructor, sec

Comment: @xcrypt: Then try `printf("this = %p\n", this);` Should print `NULL`. This means you are calling the `Draw` member method on a `NULL` object.

Comment: this == 0x00000000

But I'm not sure where I can find the result of printf(). Never used it yet sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dereference in your class, but one you don't see: `m_pCrosshair` is a member, so any access will go through the `this` pointer, which seems to be 0 according to the error. I can't find the invocation site of `GUI::Draw`, but the instance pointer there is 0 or uninitialized.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Might be NULL, too, but the access violation occurs in the line `int a = (int)m_pCrosshair;` already according to the OP. `m_pCrosshair == NULL` would not be a problem in that line.

Comment: The weird part is: InitGame() *does* get called before the Draw() method. And InitGame() *does* return true.

However, if I put a VS breakpoint at the GUI constructor, it looks like it never gets called, which is suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

Your bool PsychoBots_Game::InitGame() does not return value.

Are you sure that Draw method is being called on m_pGUI?

Are your sure  PsychoBots_Game::InitGame() is being called ? From the code your provided only pGameApp->InitApp() is called. m_pGUI is initialized in InitGame.

Comment: Yes to all, PsychoBots_Game::InitGame() is being called within pGameApp->InitApp() and returns true. Sorry for not providing that code, but it was already a lot...

Answer (score 0):

The class class GUI does not obey the rule of three (while containing a RAW pointer).

Thus you probably have made a copy of the object and the original object got deleted thus leaving you with an object with an invalid pointer.

**There is an easy way to check if this is the problem**: Make the copy constructor and assignment operator if GUI private if you get a compile time error then this is your problem.

As a side note your code contains way to many RAW pointers.
You should take a look what really needs to be pointers and what can be normal objects. In places where you must have pointers then look at using smart pointers.

Comment: This was not the problem. And I understand your concerns with the pointers and stuff. However, I am limited in how I may write my code: as a student, there's certain stuff I'm allowed and not allowed to do. As much as I hate it